# Truncate Partitions greater than year 2015

Tags: oracle-sql-developer

I need to update the data in a table partitioned by year by truncating every time the partitions greater than 2015 and inserting again the updated data from the source system. But I think that we can use only the function `VALUE LESS THAN`, there is no `GREATER THAN` function.